# SQL SERVER ¿Si ya existe el numero de transacción, sumarle 1?

Tags: sql-server

Buen día estoy elaborando un trabajo en SQL SERVER donde se me pidió sumarle un número al número de transacción que están repetidas de la tabla *TRANSACCIONESREPORTAR* para que este número de transacción pueda ser único.

Por ejemplo: en este trabajo el numero de transacción por reglamento interno  debe estar compuesto por:

> **año+mes+día+numero de sucursal+numero de agencia+numero de computadora+correlativo**

Hago la consulta a la tabla **TRANSACCIONESREPORTAR** Y veo que hay números de transacciones que se repiten porque el correlativo se genera por *default 00* en todas entonces lo que tengo que hacer es que si se repite sumarle 1, por ejemplo las transacciones que están:

> ```
> 2019120101540800
> 2019120101540800
> ```

Deben de quedar:

> ```
> 2019120101540800
> 2019120101540801
> ```

**ejemplo 2:** 
Las transacciones que están

> ```
> 2019120201490300,
> 2019120201490300,
> 2019120201490300
> ```

Deben quedar :

> ```
> 2019120201490300,
> 2019120201490301,
> 2019120201490302
> ```

Alguna idea De como hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya te han comentado, no hagas un cursor si puedes evitarlo, no es porque para este caso no fuera válido, que si puede serlo, sino porque es una muy mala práctica en un lenguaje declarativo como Sql Server.

En el ejemplo que te han expuesto, hay alguna incorrección, pero es un muy buen camino.

```
Create table TransaccionesReportar(
CodigoCorrelativo varchar(16),
OtroCampo int
);
GO
INSERT INTO TransaccionesReportar (CodigoCorrelativo, OtroCampo)
VALUES 
('2019120101540800',1),
('2019120101540800',2),
('2019120201490300',3),
('2019120201490300',4),
('2019120201490300',5);
GO
;WITH CTE
AS (SELECT CodigoCorrelativo + 
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CodigoCorrelativo
        ORDER BY CodigoCorrelativo)-1) AS NuevoCodigo,
        CodigoCorrelativo
        FROM TransaccionesReportar)
UPDATE Cte Set CodigoCorrelativo = NuevoCodigo FROM CTE;
GO
SELECT * FROM TransaccionesReportar
```

El Código recoge lo que tenga tu campo CodigoCorrelativo y siempre que sea igual, row_number se irá aumentando de 1 en 1. Cuando CodigoCorrelativo cambie, row_number empezará en 1. Por tanto tu codigo, más el autonumerador -1 es igual a lo que solicitas.

[Row_number Numerar Filas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)

[Cte: Tablas de expresión comun](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/)

[image: Imagen con los resultados]

Ok, si tienes una letra en medio, puedes variar el código así:

```
;WITH CTE
AS (SELECT 
RIGHT(CodigoCorrelativo,4) + 
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CodigoCorrelativo
    ORDER BY CodigoCorrelativo)-1)  AS NuevoCodigo,
    CodigoCorrelativo
    FROM TransaccionesReportar)
    UPDATE CTE set CodigoCorrelativo = 
        LEFT(CodigoCorrelativo,LEN(CODIGOCORRELATIVO)-4) --    ParteIzquierda
        + 
        case 
            when len(NuevoCodigo) < 4 then RIGHT('0000' +  CAST(NUEVOCODIGO AS varchar(4)),4)
        ELSE CAST(NUEVOCODIGO AS varchar(4)) END 
        from cte;
GO
SELECT * FROM TransaccionesReportar
```

Pero este escenario es para una migración de datos. O lo que significa que vas a realizar una update una vez, o alguna vez, no es para insertar registros con esta codificación.

Básicamente el código varía en que recogemos, por partes el viejo código, solo utilizando los 4 últimos dígitos como parte entera para sumar.

Existen otras modos o maneras, pero cuanto más complejo sea tú escenario, un poco más compleja será la query.

[image: Resultados]

Comment: Buen día estimado, muchas gracias por tu respuesta me ha sido de mucha utilidad,  una consulta como harías si la transaccion llevara letras de manera intermedia como la siguiente  Create table #TransaccionesReportar(
CodigoCorrelativo varchar(16),
OtroCampo int
);
GO
INSERT INTO #TransaccionesReportar (CodigoCorrelativo, OtroCampo)
VALUES 
('2019121001A10500',1),
('2019121001A10500',2),
('2019121001AF1100',3),
('2019121001AF1100',4),
('2019121001AF1100',5);
GO
estuve probando y me da el siguiente error: Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Comment: Excelente su esta respuesta fue muy completa y muy útil mil gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo aquí te deje un ejemplo con unas simples lineas de código y no usando un cursor como debes de saber es mas pesado y consume muchos recursos.

Claro tu lo harias con tu tabla.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
CodigoTran nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('2019120101540800'),('2019120101540800'),('2019120101540800'),('2019120101540800')

;WITH CTE_FOR_UPDATE AS(
SELECT CodigoTran+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CodigoTran ORDER BY CodigoTran) AS NEWCodigoTran,CodigoTran FROM @Table)
UPDATE CTE_FOR_UPDATE SET CodigoTran=NEWCodigoTran

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Aqui el ejemplo funcionando.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fc53c1f541b28a9f40baea0dfbe61065

Comment: --Buen dìa Muchas Gracias por su respuesta ha sido de mucha ayuda, una consulta como haria en el caso de que el numero de transacción llevara letras como el siguiente ejemplo:
DECLARE Table TABLE(
CodigoTran varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO Table VALUES 
('201912010A540800'),
('201912010A540800'),
('20191202AF490300'),
('20191202AF1490300'),
('20191202AF490300');
;WITH CTE_FOR_UPDATE AS(
SELECT CodigoTran+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CodigoTran ORDER BY CodigoTran) AS NEWCodigoTran,CodigoTran FROM Table)
UPDATE CTE_FOR_UPDATE SET CodigoTran=NEWCodigoTran
SELECT * FROM Table

Comment: Buen dia lograste resolverlo?

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente, lo que estás haciendo es una violación a la primera regla de normalización. Ninguna columna debe contener valores compuestos. Al menos, no deberían de existir como columna física.

Tu tabla debe quedar de esta forma (añado 2 opciones una para la creación de la tabla y otra para sólo agregar la columna calculada).

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACCIONESREPORTAR(
    fecha   date,
    sucursal char(2),
    agencia char(2),
    computadora char(2),
    correlativo tinyint,
    -- Otras columnas
    clave_transaccion AS CONCAT(CONVERT(char(8), fecha, 112),sucursal, agencia, computadora, RIGHT( 100 + correlativo, 2))
);

ALTER TABLE TRANSACCIONESREPORTAR ADD nueva_clave_transaccion AS CONCAT(CONVERT(char(8), fecha, 112),sucursal, agencia, computadora, RIGHT( 100 + correlativo, 2));

INSERT INTO TRANSACCIONESREPORTAR
VALUES  ( GETDATE(), '01', '54', '08', 0),
        ( GETDATE(), '01', '54', '08', 1);

GO

SELECT * 
FROM TRANSACCIONESREPORTAR
```

Ahora, lo complicado es mantener el correlativo. Esto es porque si 2 procesos tratan de insertar al mismo tiempo, pueden generar duplicados. Sin embargo, la opción sencilla suele ser algo así:

```
DECLARE @fecha      date = GETDATE(),
        @sucursal   char(2) = '01',
        @agencia    char(2) = '54',
        @computadora    char(2) = '08';

INSERT INTO TRANSACCIONESREPORTAR
SELECT @fecha, 
        @sucursal, 
        @agencia, 
        @computadora,
        ISNULL((SELECT MAX( correlativo) 
                FROM TRANSACCIONESREPORTAR
                WHERE fecha = @fecha
                AND sucursal = @sucursal
                AND agencia = @agencia
                AND computadora = @computadora
                ) + 1, 0);
```

El 1, se debe cambiar por un `ROW_NUMBER()` si se van a insertar varias filas al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score -1):

Podrías recorrer con un cursor y solo actualizar el dato que necesitas

```
DECLARE cursorActualiza CURSOR
    FOR SELECT * FROMTabla WHEREcampo = combinacionQueYaSabes

Open cursorActualiza

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO variableTemporal;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN
        --Logica para actualizar cada registro   
    END;
    CLOSE cursorActuliza;
DEALLOCATE cursorActualiza;
```

Recomendaría que lo hicieras dentro de una transacción para que puedas validar que sea correcto el resultado

Comment: Buen día estimado Mauricio, gracias por tu respuesta, podría pedirle un ejemplo por favor para comprender un poco mas.